# Mono & Active Directory: DirectoryServices.AccountManagement exception

Tags: c#, .net, mono, active-directory

I'm trying to integrate AD authentication into a basic .NET console app (for proof on concept) to run on Mono 3.2.8, but the following line throws an exception:

```
var domain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "server-name.local", "administrator", "password")
```

Exception:

> Invalid IL code in
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext:.ctor
>   (System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType,string,string,string):
>   method body is empty.

It runs perfectly under Windows. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Active Directory is primarily a Windows stuff. [`PrincipalContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext) is a class defined in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll`. But you can see from Mono's code base that there is no `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`,

https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class

You cannot port any Windows specific bits to Mono and Linux, but you might see if you can rewrite your logic using only `System.DirectoryServices` or `Novell.Directory.Ldap`.

Comment: Novell.Directory.Ldap was the way to go. Thanks!